# Another .htaccess Question about redirects

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

I want to redirect
/forums/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-[RANDOMNUMBER].jpg

to a static no photo file like:
/forums/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-none.jpg

I know it can be done with .htaccess I am currently experiencing lots of 404 Errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need a RegEx for this. So that any request that matches that regular expression will be redirected to the other file.

So try this:`RewriteRule /forums/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-[0-9]*.jpg /forums/uploads/profile/photo-thumb-none.jpg`